# Binding JSON web API to MySQL database programmatically - any existing solution?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, json, http

I need a declarative way of defining `GET` and `POST` requests (that will accept and return **JSON**) to query and edit a MySQL database. The server backend that will handle these requests and responses will be written in C#.

I would like to use a JSON API to perform CRUD operations and some specific queries.

---

Example desired code/pseudocode:

```
class Server
{
    private JSONBinding binding;

    public Server()
    {
        // "Bind" JSON to SQL declaratively:
        var tUsers = binding.Table("users");
        var tpuFName = tUsers.Parameter<String>("first_name");
        var tpuLName = tUsers.Parameter<String>("last_name");
        var tpuAge = tUsers.Parameter<Int32>("age");

        tUsers.AddAction("add")
            .Requires(tpuFName, tpuLName, tpuAge);

        tUsers.EditAction("edit");

        tUsers.Action("get_over_18", () => { /* query here */ });
    }
};
```

The above code would allow me to send JSON requests similar to:

```
{
    "users":
    {
        "add":
        {
            "first_name": "Foo",
            "last_name": "Bar",
            "age_name": "50"
        }
    }
}
```

This request would get automatically parsed and `(Foo, Bar, 50)` would be added in the MySQL database.

---

**Does anything similar to what I want to implement exist?**

If not, I would probably implement a reflection-based system where every database entity is a class with tagged (using attributes) properties.

Comment: Entity Framework can map between your database tables and classes, Web API can serialise/deserialise JSON into your classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben Robinson mentioned in the comments, [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) can be combined to easily bind a relational SQL database to a RESTful API.